# A predicate which holds for at most 2

Tags: verification, alloy, formal-verification

I want to write a predicate which holds for at most two items.

I tried doing one x,y: Object | 
However this did not give the desired result

I then tried one x,y: Object | x != y 
However this gave no instances

I was thinking of something along the lines of

some ..
{
   one..
}

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`one` forces there to be only one atom, but `x, y` is two. One way to do this would be `some disj x, y: Object | no z: Object - x - y | ...`